# check if an element from a list exists in a strings of a txt file (not working) Python

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I have tried many ways but I do not get any output at all. I have a list containing different types of strings:

```
lst=['ATCGG','GTAACGCT','AATCGAT',...]
```

and I have a text file as below:

```
>seq1
NNNGTAACGCTNNN
>seq2
NNNNNAATCGATNNNN
>seq3
NNNNNNNN
.
.
.
```

I want to print lines of the text file if any item in the list exists in the line. Based on the examples above, the desired output should be:

```
NNNGTAACGCTNNN
NNNNNAATCGATNNNN
```

I used the command below but nothing is getting printed out:

```
main_file =  open('test_file.txt', 'r')
contn = main_file.read()
#print(contn)


for dna in contn:
    if any(i in dna for i in lst):
        print(dna)
```

Comment: pretty sure you need `readlines` instead of `read` since you'll be checking character by character currently

Comment: yay - that solved the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An explicit loop version for intuitiveness:

```py
def find_lines_containing_any(filename, wanted_list):
    with open(filename, 'r') as dna_file:
       for dna_line in dna_file:
            for wanted in wanted_list:
                if wanted in dna_line:
                    yield dna_line

for dna in find_lines_containing_any('test_file.txt', lst):
    print(dna)
```

Comment: dna is undefined, how would this run?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Check my edited version

Answer (score 3):

You need `readlines` instead of `read`, read will be creating a single string so when you iterate, `dna` is actually just individual characters

```
contn = main_file.read()
```

should be

```
contn = main_file.readlines()
```

Answer (score 1):

With `for dna in contn`, you are iterating over the characters as `read()` returns a `str` object, you can simply do:

```
main_file =  open('test_file.txt', 'r')
for line in main_file:
    if any(i in line for i in lst):
        print(line)
```